# how to get all records from one table and based on that each record fetch all records which associated to the first table records in mvc 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, petapoco

I want to fetch all records from one table called Visitor and i have another table called booking_visitor

my visitor table

Visitor

VisitorId
VisitorName
Email
Phone
Photo

Booking_visitor

BookingId F.k
VisitorId F.k

i want to get all records from visitor table and based on that each id present in the Booking_visitor table fetch each record having VisitorId value

if 
VistorId is 1 for first record and that id is comes three times in Booking_visitor table the for the visitorid = 1 it should show three records below that record

i have tried by my logic but it seems i am not getting proper result may be my controller code is wrong or my razor view is wrong

Here it what i have tried

```
   var visitor= db.Fetch<Visitor>("Select VisitorId,VisitorName from Visitors");

        foreach (var vs in Visitors)
        {
            ViewBag.VisitorsAmount= db.Query<Bookingvw>("select b.BookingId,bd.BookingDetailId,v.VisitorId,v.VisitorName,bd.CheckIn,bd.CheckOut from Booking_visitor bv " +
           "inner join Booking b on b.BookingId= bv.BookingId" +
           "inner join Visitors v on v.VisitorId= bv.VisitorId" +
           $"inner join BookingDetails bd on bd.BookingId= b.BookingId where v.VisitorId= {vs.VisitorId} ");
            "group by b.BookingId, bd.BookingDetailId, v.VisitorId, v.VisitorName, bd.CheckIn, bd.CheckOut ");*/

        }
        return View(visitor);


 @model IEnumerable<Visitors>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.VisitorName</td>
            </tr>

        }
            <tr>
                @{
                    var vsamt = (IEnumerable<Bookingvw>)ViewBag.VisitorsAmount;
                }
                <th>
                    Booking Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Check In
                </th>
            </tr>


            @foreach (var item2 in vsamt )
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.BookinId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.CheckIn)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }

        }
```

i want a hierarchical result for first visitor is there any result then show that result below first visitor

Comment: I suggest you study and learn before you code. You have too many issues in your code. What is `Visitors`? You keep looping and setting `VisitorsAmount`, if you keep setting a different value to a variable in a loop, what value will it have? We don't know if you're getting any results from the db or not...too many issues to help you out.

Comment: You can direct use linq to get your `Booking_visitor` like `var booking = db.Booking_visitor.Include(x=>x.Visitor);`  like this you can access all booking visitors also you get all your visitors with its  booking like `var visitors= db.Visitor.Include(x=>x.Booking_visitor);`  as EF im model you provide reference then u can access like this.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite expensive to make the second query as many times as visitors count.
What a I would do is to fetch all Visitors (as you did), then fetch all Bookingvw (carrying **`bv.VisitorId`** info) but without the clause **`v.VisitorId = {vs.VisitorId}`**. So 2 queries - 2 lists.
Then in cshtml instead of **`(IEnumerable<Bookingvw>)ViewBag.VisitorsAmount`**, you could use the following **`(IEnumerable<Bookingvw>)ViewBag.VisitorsAmount.Where(x => x.VisitorId == item.VisitorId)`**.

Hope this helps